# Typehinting: Why does python self-referencing require quotes?

Tags: python, type-hinting

According to [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#forward-references),

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

We're presented with the following (illegal) code:

```py
class Tree:
    def __init__(self, left: Tree, right: Tree):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

This seems like an intuitive implementation of typehinting, and one would expect that since the symbol `Tree` is defined, python would know about it.

My working theory is that, although python is run line-by-line, the symbol `Tree` hasn't yet been added to the namespace dict because the `Tree` class is still in the process of being defined. Thus although the *symbol* exists, the *object* doesn't yet exist. Is this right? Is there more nuance than I'm giving it?

Comment: "and one would expect that since the symbol Tree is defined, python would know about it." *but that's the thing*, it **is not defined**. Forget type-hints, instead, just try to do something like `Tree.foo = 32` inside of the `class Tree` block and it will raise the *same error*

Comment: "My working theory is that, although python is run line-by-line, the symbol Tree hasn't yet been added to the namespace dict because the Tree class is still in the process of being defined. Thus although the symbol exists, the object doesn't yet exist." This sounds about right, but I don't know what you mean by "the symbol exists". The symbol doesn't exist, if by symbol you mean variable. The variable will only exist after the class definition statement is done executing.

Comment: For example, if I do `foo = foo + 1` it will raise `NameError`. Same exact issue.

Comment: So class definition statements are just like any other piece of executable code in Python. They result in a variable being defined in whatever scope you are doing, but that happens at the very end of the statement, not at the beginning.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'd say "symbol" means the string `'Tree'`. Which indeed already does exist very early, you can [print it inside](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PzknsbhYIaQoNdWKSwEICooy80o04uMLSxNz8hJzU@PjNf//BwA).

Comment: @KellyBundy this is exactly what I meant, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, Python is run "line-by-line", but that is the *bytecode*. Let's consider the following example:

```
In [3]: class Foo:
   ...:     def bar(self) -> Foo:
   ...:         return Foo()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <module>
----> 1 class Foo:
      2     def bar(self) -> Foo:
      3         return Foo()

Input In [3], in Foo()
      1 class Foo:
----> 2     def bar(self) -> Foo:
      3         return Foo()

NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

And let's look at the bytecode dissasembly:

```
In [5]: dis.dis(
   ...:     """
   ...: class Foo:
   ...:     def bar(self) -> Foo:
   ...:         return Foo()
   ...: """
   ...: )
  2           0 LOAD_BUILD_CLASS
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (<code object Foo at 0x10b26bc90, file "<dis>", line 2>)
              4 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Foo')
              6 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              8 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Foo')
             10 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (Foo)
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object Foo at 0x10b26bc90, file "<dis>", line 2>:
  2           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              2 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Foo')
              6 STORE_NAME               2 (__qualname__)

  3           8 LOAD_NAME                3 (Foo)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (('return',))
             12 BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP      1
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object bar at 0x10b264d40, file "<dis>", line 3>)
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Foo.bar')
             18 MAKE_FUNCTION            4 (annotations)
             20 STORE_NAME               4 (bar)
             22 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object bar at 0x10b264d40, file "<dis>", line 3>:
  4           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Foo)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

Look at the top level, the one that begins with `LOAD_BUILD_CLASS`. That essentially puts `__build_class__` on the top of the stack, which is the helper function which is used to actually create class objects. If you want to understand the details of what happens in the function, [start reading from here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation). But for our purposes, it basically chooses the correct metaclass (so `type` unless you specify otherwise, or inherit from a class that does), and prepares the class namespace, and does `class_object = metaclass(name, bases, namespace, **kwds)`. For the curious, the class namespace is essentially created by initializing it, `namespace = {}` then `exec(body, globals(), namespace)` (although not exactly, again, read more of the data model documentation for the nitty-gritty details).

But basically, as you can see, it isn't until *after* the class creation function is called that the variable is created:

```
    12 STORE_NAME               0 (Foo)
```

Now, the:

```
    3           8 LOAD_NAME                3 (Foo)
```

Which is used to create the return annotation will search the global namespace for a `Foo`, and doesn't find one yet, and it raises an error!

Note, you can use `from __future__ import annotations` and this will *work*, essentially, the evaluation of an annotation is postponed, the annotation is stored essentially as a string in annotations. <strike>Note, `dis` does not actually seem to give a different output when I try it after using `from __future__ import annotations` but that might just be a limitation of the `dis` module</strike>.

If we use the `__future__` import in the code passed to `dis`, we see:

```
In [6]: dis.dis(
   ...:     """
   ...: from __future__ import annotations
   ...: class Foo:
   ...:     def bar(self) -> Foo:
   ...:         return Foo()
   ...: """
   ...: )
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (0)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 (('annotations',))
              4 IMPORT_NAME              0 (__future__)
              6 IMPORT_FROM              1 (annotations)
              8 STORE_NAME               1 (annotations)
             10 POP_TOP

  3          12 LOAD_BUILD_CLASS
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object Foo at 0x10819c2f0, file "<dis>", line 3>)
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Foo')
             18 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             20 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Foo')
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            2
             24 STORE_NAME               2 (Foo)
             26 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object Foo at 0x10819c2f0, file "<dis>", line 3>:
  3           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (__name__)
              2 STORE_NAME               1 (__module__)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Foo')
              6 STORE_NAME               2 (__qualname__)

  4           8 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Foo')
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (('return',))
             12 BUILD_CONST_KEY_MAP      1
             14 LOAD_CONST               2 (<code object bar at 0x10819c240, file "<dis>", line 4>)
             16 LOAD_CONST               3 ('Foo.bar')
             18 MAKE_FUNCTION            4 (annotations)
             20 STORE_NAME               3 (bar)
             22 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             24 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object bar at 0x10819c240, file "<dis>", line 4>:
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (Foo)
              2 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              4 RETURN_VALUE
```

And note, that "line" becomes:

```
      4           8 LOAD_CONST               0 ('Foo')
```

Anyway, read more about that [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/)

Comment: For me, the future-import changes `LOAD_NAME   3 (Foo)` to `LOAD_CONST   0 ('Foo')`.

Comment: To be sure: Did you do the future-import inside the string given to `dis`?

Comment: @KellyBundy aaaahhh that makes sense, I guess. Although, compiling and `exec`ing the string works just fine without the future import in the string, as long as it has been imported already. I'm sure there's an explanation somewhere